# Passing URL parameter to another URL

Tags: jquery, parsing, url

I'm trying to pass a URL parameter. I have parser the URL using the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = 'http://sitename.com/Manual/module_1_3.htm';
//Create a new link with the url as its href:
var a = $('<a>', {
   href: url
});
var sResult = '<b>Protocol:</b> ' + a.prop('protocol') + '<br/>'     + '<b>Host name: </b>' + a.prop('hostname') + '<br/>' 
+ '<b>Path: </b>' + a.prop('pathname') + '<br/>' 


$('span').html(sResult);
```

});

The output is:

```
    Protocol: https:
    Host: www.site-name.com
    Path: /Manual/module_1_3.htm
```

My question is how do I go about passing the path to another page within
the same domain

Thanks

Comment: Append it to the querystring. Just ensure you URL encode it, though

Comment: Pass to where, for what purpose? Are you asking about a standard, run-of-the-mill, garden variety query string parameter? If so, what specifically is unclear? `/some/document.htm?parametername=value` with `value` being the properly URL-encoded path value ...?

Comment: yes, I want to append the path to pass it another page.